# How to address terminal not allowing me to run "gem install debug"

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, visual-studio-debugging

Apologies if this question isn't formatted too well.

I'm working through The Odin Project right now and am now doing the Ruby path (really liked how data structures and algorithms would be included)

Right now, the section I'm working on is the debugging in VScode. The first step was to run the command:

```
gem install debug
```

But upon doing this, the command merely brings that process to the foreground without really executing anything.

I checked my gems and whether they needed updated, but even commands like

```
gem update
gem outdated
```

didn't work.

What should I do to address this issue?

Going further into detail with what I tried above, those commands simply did the same thing.

```
gem update 
gem outdated
```

These both started in the foreground without actually doing anything.

The command below worked for me, and it printed the following after it

```
gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abbrev (default: 0.1.0)
base64 (default: 0.1.1)
benchmark (default: 0.2.0)
bigdecimal (default: 3.1.1)
bundler (2.3.14, default: 2.3.7)
byebug (11.1.3)
cgi (default: 0.3.1)
coderay (1.1.3)
csv (default: 3.2.2)
date (default: 3.2.2)
debug (1.4.0)
delegate (default: 0.2.0)
did_you_mean (default: 1.6.1)
diff-lcs (1.5.0)
digest (default: 3.1.0)
drb (default: 2.1.0)
english (default: 0.7.1)
erb (default: 2.2.3)
error_highlight (default: 0.3.0)
etc (default: 1.3.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.1)
fiddle (default: 1.1.0)
fileutils (default: 1.6.0)
find (default: 0.1.1)
forwardable (default: 1.3.2)
getoptlong (default: 0.1.1)
io-console (default: 0.5.11)
io-nonblock (default: 0.1.0)
io-wait (default: 0.2.1)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.4)
irb (default: 1.4.1)
json (default: 2.6.1)
logger (default: 1.5.0)
matrix (0.4.2)
method_source (1.0.0)
minitest (5.15.0)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.1)
net-ftp (0.1.3)
net-http (default: 0.2.0)
net-imap (0.2.3)
net-pop (0.1.1)
net-protocol (default: 0.1.2)
net-smtp (0.3.1)
nkf (default: 0.1.1)
observer (default: 0.1.1)
open-uri (default: 0.2.0)
open3 (default: 0.1.1)
openssl (default: 3.0.0)
optparse (default: 0.2.0)
ostruct (default: 0.5.2)
pathname (default: 0.2.0)
power_assert (2.0.1)
pp (default: 0.3.0)
prettyprint (default: 0.1.1)
prime (0.1.2)
pry (0.14.1)
pry-byebug (3.10.1)
pstore (default: 0.1.1)
psych (default: 4.0.3)
racc (default: 1.6.0)
rake (13.0.6)
rbs (2.1.0)
rdoc (default: 6.4.0)
readline (default: 0.0.3)
readline-ext (default: 0.1.4)
reline (default: 0.3.0)
resolv (default: 0.2.1)
resolv-replace (default: 0.1.0)
rexml (3.2.5)
rinda (default: 0.1.1)
rspec (3.11.0)
rspec-core (3.11.0)
rspec-expectations (3.11.0)
rspec-mocks (3.11.1)
rspec-support (3.11.0)
rss (0.2.9)
ruby2_keywords (default: 0.0.5)
securerandom (default: 0.1.1)
set (default: 1.0.2)
shellwords (default: 0.1.0)
singleton (default: 0.1.1)
stringio (default: 3.0.1)
strscan (default: 3.0.1)
syslog (default: 0.1.0)
tempfile (default: 0.1.2)
test-unit (3.5.3)
time (default: 0.2.0)
timeout (default: 0.2.0)
tmpdir (default: 0.1.2)
tsort (default: 0.1.0)
typeprof (0.21.2)
un (default: 0.2.0)
uri (default: 0.11.0)
weakref (default: 0.1.1)
yaml (default: 0.2.0)
zlib (default: 2.1.1)
```

What are some other things I can do to debug this issue?

Comment: Might be a network related issue. Try running in verbose mode (`gem install -V debug`) to see where it gets stuck...